# How to get know that boost::interprocess::message_queue was removed from system?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

I create Sender/Receiver wrapper based on `boost::interprocess::message_queue` for sending messages from one process and receiving it in another, you can view sources here: https://gist.github.com/onto/c322bb0a33433b775966

There is a problem, if I destruct sender object, `message_queue` was removed from system, but receiver wasn't notifyed of it. How to fix it?

If `message_queue` not exists on creating `MessageQueueReceiver` object it throws an exception, it's normal behaviour for me, but if i remove `message_queue` from system `boost::interprocess::message_queue::receive` doesn't throw anything, `boost::interprocess::message_queue::timed_receive` return `false` but it just mean that timeout expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution, I throw an exception when timeout expired and recreate MessageQueueReceiver object.